# Exchange 2010 migration to an alternate IMAP server

Tags: imap, exchange-2010

I need some advice and help on how to do a migration AWAY from Exchange 2010 to an alternative IMAP server in the most efficient manner.

Basically we have 20 users that are all using MS Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2010 as a demo to see if it would be worth using in our company.  I must point out that the Exchange server is not in our company but hosted by a 3rd party provider so we have no administrative access to the server except for what we are provided by their hosting. So running scripts and tools directly on the exchange server for instance will not be possible.

My question is how we go about migrating mailboxes back from exchange to another IMAP4 compliant mail system.  So far the simplest method I can come up with is to set up the new IMAP account within Outlook and then manually drag across each folder individually until the entire users mailbox has been transferred across.

Has anyone done this before and could maybe offer some suggestions on automation or tools that could be capable of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MsgExtract](http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/) for migrating the email accounts. MsgExtract can read the Exchange Server data via Outlook (MAPI) end export it to an IMAP account.

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)